# How to edit a closed shape drawn by Path Tool in GIMP?

Tags: gimp, shapes, patterns

I created a custom shape with custom pattern with the following steps:

1. Drawing the border lines with `Path Tool`
2. Making a closed shape by `Selection from Path`
3. Selecting the closed shape with `Magic Wand`
4. Filling the closed shape with solid color or pattern by `Bucket Fill Tool`

Now I want to re-design the shape by moving the controlling points of Bezier Curve, but the shape is now independent of the initial points set by the `Path Tool`.

My problem is that after Step 2, the closed shape is independent of the initial drawing points, and thus not editable. On the other hand, I want to edit the shape when it is filled with color.

How can I create a custom filled shape, which is still editable by moving controller points?

Comment: I'm not sure what that second step there is for... no selection was mentioned, and you close a shape by holding ctrl and clicking on the path's starting point.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think it's possible to edit a shape directly.

But you can edit a path after it was transformed to a selection.

Go to "Windows > Dockable Dialogs > Paths", (by default its docked next to the layers tab) here you can edit, duplicate and even export paths.

After editing the initial path you need to create a new selection and fill it again.

When drawing something more complex, I usually use the duplicate path feature to maintain a few backups.

Hope that helps.